Decomposition of Fock space
Consider the regular (bosonic) Fock space in 1D (for simplicity):
$$\mathcal{F}_{+} = \bigoplus\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} S_{+}H^{\otimes n}(\mathbb{R}),$$
and say $H(\mathbb{R}) = L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Since
$$L^2(\mathbb{R}) = L^2(\mathbb{R}^{+}) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{R}^{-}),$$
I am interested in how the direct sum
$$\left(\bigoplus\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} S_{+}L^{2^{\otimes n}}(\mathbb{R^{+}})\right) \oplus \left(\bigoplus\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} S_{+}L^{2^{\otimes n}}(\mathbb{R^{-}})\right)$$
can be related to $\mathcal{F}_{+}$? I assume they are not equal?

Well, it holds that $F(H_1\oplus H_2)\simeq F(H_1)\otimes F(H_2)$, but this is not what you're looking for, correct?

I wasn't aware of that, thank you! But yes, that only partially answers my question. I would then also like to know what $F(H_1) \oplus F(H_2)$ `is', I mean how it's different from $F(H_1 \oplus H_2)$? For example, what if you had the system $F(H_1) \oplus F(H_2)$, could then a unitary transformation take you to $F(H_1 \oplus H_2)$?

Well, all finite-dimensional complex Hilbert spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic; and all infinite-dimensional separable complex Hilbert spaces are isomorphic. So under these conditions: Yes. But the isomorphism in general might/is not canonical. For the decomposition I've written there is a natural isomorphism. This is shown, for example, in the books by A. Arai.

Aha, I see! Thank you!

For example, consider two finite-dimensional single-particle space $H_1$ and $H_2$ with dimensions $d_1$ and $d_2$, respectively. Then the dimension of the fermionic Fock space $F(H_1 \oplus H_2)$ is $2^{d_1+d_2}$, which agrees with the dimension of $F(H_1)\otimes F(H_2)$, but not with the dimension of $F(H_1)\oplus F(H_2)$ ($2^{d_1} +2^{d_2}$), except in trivial cases. --Bosonic Fock spaces are always infinite-dimensional, however, even for a finite single-particle space.
